# JavaFX - bring window to focus on key combination

Tags: java, javafx, window, keyboard-events, keyevent

I want to bring my window into focus when the key combination `Ctrl + Space` is entered on the keyboard and when the scene is not in focus. This is what I have so far:

```
mScene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if (e.isControlDown() && e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
            System.out.println("Ctrl + Space!");
            //bring window to focus
            //...
        }
    });
```

However, it only works if `mScene` is in focus. How do I get this to work when the window is minimized?

Comment: Not sure there's a way to do that. What would you want to happen, for example, if the user had opened several instances of the application and had them all minimized...?

Comment: You gonna need something not based on JavaFX I think. All JavaFX Listeners need an active / opened window.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I used JNativeHook to listen for global keyboard events (https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook).

Comment: @Stardust You could have used an awt keyListener as well, as it is not bound to a window/(awt)application. That way there is no need for additional libraries.